# Trouble setting combobox selectedindex from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedindex

I am trying to set the selectedindex on another form (form2) based on the user selected index on the first form (form1).

I am getting the value with this code but it returns a negative number.

```
public int SelectedComboIndex
{
   get { return comboBox1.SelectedIndex; }
}
```

And I am trying to set the comboBox Index by

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = form1.SelectedComboIndex;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to do this?

Edit: More code for where its calling the code on form1

```
Form1 form1 = null;
public Form2(Form1 parentForm1) : this()
{
    form1 = parentForm1;
}
```

Comment: A `SelectedIndex` value of `-1` means that nothing is selected, are you sure something is selected?  The default will be `-1` for the `combBox1.SelectedIndex`

Comment: thats exactly the negative number Im getting. I am sure Im selecting it, but just trying to carry over the selection to the other combobox on form2

Comment: post your code for form1 and form2 where you are setting the property SelectedComboIndex and where you are using it

Comment: It was posted above. Ill add more

Comment: Can you show the method that calls this code : comboBox1.SelectedIndex = form1.SelectedComboIndex; ?

Comment: If Im not wrong, which there is a good chance, the SelectedComboIndex is getting the selectedindex, or should be, and by using the public Form2 portion, that calls the form1.SelectedComboIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to usually leave any sort of UI alterations in the `Load` method of the form, that way the form has a chance to initialize properly and all bindings are setup before you actually make changes. The Constructors should only be used to set internal state.

```
private Form1 _parentForm;
public Form2(Form1 parentForm) : this()
{
    _parentForm = parentForm;
}

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponents();
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12f, FontStyle.Regular); 
    dropdown(); 
    if(_parentForm != null)
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = _parentForm.SelectedComboIndex; 
    comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; 
}
```

Try that out and see if it works. Just be sure to add the Load handler to the form properly (either through the designer or in code via `this.Load += new EventHandler(Form2_Load)`

Answer (score 2):

A combobox returns a negative value (-1 normally) if no index is selected.

So I believe (I have not checked) that if you set a negative value for the SelectedIndex property, all you are  going to do is clear the selection in your combobox.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This just restates what I've already mentioned above, its not really an answer, just how the ComboBox works

Answer (score 0):

`Note: You should rename all your components to something more useful than controlType1, controlType2 etc. This is good for both you and us.`

As other people said if `form1.SelectedComboIndex` returns -1 (because `form1.comboBox1` has nothing selected) then the line `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = form1.SelectedComboIndex` will (correctly) set `comboBox1`'s value to nothing.

Additionally, just because there's text present in your `ComboBox` doesn't mean it's got a selected value. Make sure you combo box has actually selected a value (not just changed its text).  You can force picking a value by setting the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`.  Both other styles allow user entry of custom values.

If you want users to be able to type, then consider setting `AutoCompleteMode` to `SuggestAppend` and `AutoCompleteSource` to `ListItems`.  This makes it easier to correctly select values from the combobox rather than just change the text (accidentally leaving it null).

Comment: so i am getting the vibe that it is this line of code comboBox1.SelectedIndex = form1.SelectedComboIndex;